# Could not make temporary scratch layer permanent

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I want to make a temporary scratch layer permanent but it shows  `Could not make temporary scratch layer permanent. Error: Creation of field addr:street_1 failed (OGR error: Can't create field addr_str_4 in Shape DBF file, reason unknown.)`

How can I fix this error?

[image]

This is my attribute table.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information, especially on the data type and contents of faulty columns.

Comment: I use QuickOSM to make a Building Layer and I want to save it in .shp

Comment: It would help if you shared the list of field names in your scratch layer. I suspect maybe you used an invalid character in a field name or have duplicate field names, or something along those lines

Comment: @she_weeds Sorry for late reply, is this what you want to see ?

Comment: Can you share a full list of all your field names? You could go to the layer properties -> Fields and take a screenshot of the list of fields

Comment: How many columns do you have, shapefiles have a limit of 255 columns. Error would make sense if addr_str_4 was the name of the 256th column.

Comment: Can you save as another format, e.g. gpkg? While shapefiles are (still) used very commonly in GIS, they are an outdated format with many limitations - including number of fields, allowable field name format and length, any of which might be tripping you up. If you can use a more modern format, your problem may go away.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a field called "addr:street_1" ???. If so, then the problem is the colon (:). You've to change it.